# Can't rename columns with dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-queries

Renaming columns in a query is a very basic and common task for any sql admin/developer. But today I faced this problem where I needed to select the table name of several hundreds of tables and match it with the latest entry in each table that was selected previously.

In the end I wanted something like this:

```
event_id | date       | tbl_name
==================================
68       | 31-12-1998 | tb_x
56       | 31-11-2001 | tb_y
```

To get the event_id and date were easy enough with a dynamic query but when I try to add the column **tbl_name** it fails.

The procedure is simple:

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + 'SELECT event_id, date, '+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+' as tbl_name FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ' 
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME not like 'event_%') AS t
...
exec (@sql)
```

In the end the query should look something like this:

```
SELECT event_id, date, 'event_b559453b' as tbl_name
FROM event_b559453b
UNION
...
SELECT event_id, date, 'event_b03c4520' as tbl_name
FROM event_b559453b
```

The strange thing (to me) is that if you run that last query it will do as expected but if you use **exec @sql** it will fail with an error saying **Invalid column name 'event_????'**. Could anyone tell me why the column renaming isn't happening, and if there's a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I'm relatively new to this!

Comment: Does: `"SELECT event_id, date, "+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+"` as tbl_name work?  I assume quotename is a UDF (user defined function)  or perhaps..`"SELECT event_id, date, '"+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+"' as tbl_name`

Comment: @xQbert `QUOTENAME()` is a [vendor function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).

Comment: You've got a double quote in your code: `SELECT @sql = @sql + "`.  Is that present in your actual code?  A double quote is a field name identifier, not a string literal identifier.  It should be a single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the double quote. And try using coalesce like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ' UNION ','') + 'SELECT event_id, date, ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' as tbl_name FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME not like 'event_%'

SELECT @sql --look at what your executing
--EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Could you just tell me why it wasn't working before? I had the double quotes right in my actual query (:P typos). Was it the triple quotes?

Comment: Well I also use coalesce to add UNION to all the queries and there is no trailing UNION(extra one at the end). As far as the "triple quotes"(three single quotes), if you want to add 1 single quote in a between two outer single quotes, you need to have 2 single quotes. So SELECT '  ''   ' will return 1 single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @sql <> '' THEN ' UNION ' ELSE '' END +
      'SELECT event_id, date, '''+TABLE_NAME+''' as tbl_name FROM [' + TABLE_NAME + '] ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME not like 'event_%'
...
EXEC(@sql)
```